# Как получить тип аргумента функции или ее возвращаемый тип?

Tags: c++, типы, c++14

Очередной странный вопрос. Навеян книгой *Discovering Modern C++* Готтшлига.
Пытаюсь написать шаблон, который бы возвращал функтор, применяющий некоторую функцию рекурсивно предопределенное количество раз. Примерно так:

```
template<typename Func, typename X, int N>
class Recurs
{
public:
    Recurs(Func f):f(f){}
    X operator()(X x)
    {
        return f(Recurs<Func,X,N-1>(f)(x));
    }
private:
    Func f;
};

template<typename Func, typename X>
class Recurs<Func,X,1>
{
public:
    Recurs(Func f):f(f){}
    X operator()(X x)
    {
        return f(x);
    }
private:
    Func f;
};
```

Так как использование в духе

```
auto f = [](double x) { return cos(x); };
Recurs<decltype(f),double,10> r(f);
r(0.1);
```

душу не греет, сделал такую функцию:

```
template<int N, typename X, typename Func>
auto calc_N(Func f, X x) -> decltype(f(x))
{
    return Recurs<Func,X,N>(f)(x);
}
```

Функция сама по переданным значениям выводит типы, так что можно вычислять как

```
calc_N<10>(f,0.1);
```

Но мне не понравилось, что каждый раз создается объект `Recurs...`. Хотелось бы получать его один раз, и вызывать как функтор - типа,

```
template<int N, typename Func>
decltype(auto) make_N(Func f)
...

auto g = make_N<10>(f);
g(0.1);
```

И вот тут у меня затык. Я написал примерно так -

```
template<int N, typename Func>
decltype(auto) make_N(Func f)
{
    return Recurs<Func,???,N>(f);
}
```

но что мне теперь писать вместо `???`. В принципе, меня устроит в данном случае и тип аргумента `f`, и тип ее возвращаемого значения (для рекурсии они должны совпадать), но как их записать?

И еще - насколько я помню, `decltype(auto)` - это уже C++14. А можно ли такое сотворить на версиях языка помладше, и как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ничего Вы там не напишите, т.к. в общем виде понять, что за тип аргумента ожидается нельзя. Так же как и вывести возвращаемое значение, в общем виде, не удастся. Что значит в общем виде? Значит, что для указателей на функции это сделать можно, а для функторов — нет.

Но почему не сделать по другому? Просто уберите `X` из `Recurs` и оставьте его локальным для вызова `operator()()`:

```
template<typename Func, int N>
class Recurs
{
public:
    Recurs(Func f):f(f) {}
    template<typename  X>
    X operator()(X x)
    {
        return f(Recurs<Func, N - 1>(f)(x));
    }
private:
    Func f;
};
```

И всё будет работать так, как Вы того хотели.

Comment: Блин. "Как я сам не дотумкал" (с) :) Спасибо!

Comment: А еще вопрос задать можно - под шумок :) - а как, например, передать функцию, которая перегружена для разных типов? Например, `make_N<10>(cos)` - как пояснить, что я хочу передать `cos`, которая для `double`, а не какая-то иная?

Comment: @Harry, нужно сделать явное приведение: `make_N<10>(static_cast<double(*)(double)>(cos))`

Comment: И снова спасибо! :)

Answer (score 0):

То есть Вы хотите вместо, например

```
int calcSum(int count) {
   int sum = 0;
   for (int n = 0; n < count; ++n)
      ++sum;
   return sum;
}
...
for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
   int sum = calcSum(10);
   ...
}
```

чтобы было

```
template<int count>
int calcSum() {
   int sum = 0;
   for (int n = 0; n < count; ++n)
      ++sum;
   return sum;
}
...
for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
   int sum = calcSum<n>();
   ...
}
```

И при этом не создавалось 10 одинаковых функций.

Тут есть 2 варианта. Первый вариант объявить функцию `inline`.

Второй вариант таков:

```
void incSum(int n, int &sum) {
   if (n > 0)
      incSum(n-1, ++sum);
}
int calcSum(int n) {
   int sum = 0;
   incSum(n, sum);
   return sum;
}
...
for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
   int sum = calcSum(n);
   ...
}
```

Перейдём к шаблонам:

```
template<typename CountT, typename SumT>
void incSum(CountT n, SumT &sum) {
   if (n > 0)
      incSum(n-1, ++sum);
}
template<typename CountT, typename SumT>
SumT calcSum(CountT n) {
   SumT sum = 0;
   incSum<CountT, SumT>(n, sum);
   return sum;
}
...
for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
   int sum = calcSum<int, int>(n);
   ...
}
```

Обобщим алгоритм:

```
template<typename CountT, typename SumT>
class FuncT {
public:
   virtual void f(CountT n, SumT &sum) = 0;
};
template<typename CountT, typename SumT>
class IncSumT : public FuncT<CountT, SumT> {
public:
   void f(CountT n, SumT &sum) {
      if (n > 0)
         incSum(n-1, ++sum);
   }
};
template<typename CountT, typename SumT>
SumT calcSum(CountT n, FuncT<CountT, SumT> &func) {
   SumT sum = 0;
   func.f(n, sum);
   return sum;
}
...
IncSumT<int, int> ist;
for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
   int sum = calcSum<int, int>(n, ist);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Вы не поняли. Я ищу обобщенное решение, с шаблонами. И ищу, как мне, передав в шаблонную функцию функтор, получить в этом шаблоне возвращаемый этой функцией тип. То, что вы предлагаете - это рекурсия обычных функций, а не шаблонных. Тут мы все типы знаем заранее.